# Android onDownloadStart() in WebView work on Device but not on emulator

Tags: android, webview, download

I have implemented a download module for images in my app. They are in `WebView`. Although, I have a strange bug that the method `onDownloadStart()` is not called when I'm running app on emulator. The same API (22) I have in my device but it's working brillant there. What is the case? Any ideas? This is how I attach the download listener to `WebView`:

```
ExportModule exportModule = new ExportModule(activity.getBaseContext(), activity, this.webView);
this.webView.addJavascriptInterface(exportModule, "jsint");
this.webView.setDownloadListener(exportModule);
```

The code from `@JavascriptInterface` is run from it but then `onDownloadSart()` is not called as in device. `onDownloadStart()` from `ExportModule` class:

```
@Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
        System.out.println("IM IN onDwoanloadStart");
        String intentType = "image/png";
        String fileName = "img.png";
        try {
            if(url != null) {
                FileOutputStream fos;
                fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                //conversion stuff
                fos.write(decodedStr);
                fos.getFD().sync();
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                File filePath = new File(String.valueOf(context.getFilesDir()));
                File newFile = new File(filePath, fileName);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".FileProvider", newFile));
                sendIntent.setType(intentType);
                context.startActivity(sendIntent);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is this an *emulator* or an *emulator with play services*

Comment: @sziraqui do you mean Google API's ? Is that important?

Comment: Yes. I feel its important coz thats the only difference between an emulator without plays services and a normal android device

Comment: @sziraqui there is no difference in using emulator with Google API and without it :(

Comment: The whole Google Play services framework is the difference. The WebView implementation on *emulator* and *emulator with google api* is different

Comment: @sziraqui I mean, there is no difference because on both `onDownloadStart()` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue on Android Studio 3.6.3 for macOS, it can resolved by the following:

1. Make sure your emulator supports Google Play Store.
2. Disable Chrome from Settings.
3. Go to Google Play store and find Android System WebView, make sure it is the official one from Google.
4. Most probably it may be disabled. You will find "Update" option is enabled. Click on Update button.

Now restart your app and you will find the "onDownloadStart()" works fine.

[image: Emulator supports Google Play Store.]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]